# Why is there a need for multiple cryptocurrencies?

Tags: cryptocurrency

Why can't all blockchains use the same cryptocurrency like Bitcoin? Why do each of them have to invent a new cryptocurrency?

Comment: You can get a lot richer if you start your own ponzi scheme, rather than joining someone else's when it's already very late in the game.

Comment: Cryptocurrencies have different characteristics. See here: https://www.ig.com/en/cryptocurrency-trading/cryptocurrency-comparison